# Tar an entire folder EXCEPT a few files and folders?

Tags: linux, tar

I have a folder structure like so:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
folder1
folder2
```

Without writing each file, how can I tar zip all the files and folders, except file1 and folder1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tar has an --exclude switch.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `--exclude=pattern` option which prevents any file or member whose name matches the wildcard (pattern) from being operated on. For example, to create an archive with all the contents of the directory `src` except for files whose names end in `.exe`, use the command `tar -cf src.tar --exclude='*.exe' src`

Answer (score 1):

> *Without writing each file, how can I tar zip all the files and folders, except file1 and folder1?*

Assuming the main folder that contains all the files/folders you want to compress is located at `/home/admin/mystuff/` (ie `/home/admin/mystuff/file1`, `/home/admin/mystuff/folder1/`, etc), either of the following should work.

---

If you're currently inside the `/home/admin/` folder, you could do this:

```
tar -cz --exclude mystuff/file1 --exclude mystuff/folder1/ -f my_new_file.tar.gz mystuff
```

---

Or, if you're inside the directory you want to compress (in this case, `/home/admin/mystuff/`), you could do:

```
tar -cz --exclude file1 --exclude folder1/ -f my_new_file.tar.gz .
```

---

Note the dot at the end of the second option.

Also note that I used `tar -cz` because I prefer `.tar.gz` files... If you only want a `.tar` file, you can just change the command to `tar -c --exclude [...]` (dropping the `z` from `-cz`) and then change the output file from `my_new_file.tar.gz` to `my_new_file.tar`.